# How to check for condition inside a macro?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I have defined a macro like this,

```
#define SELECTED_SITE_ID (SITE_MANAGER.selectedSite.siteCollectionIdentifier)
```

It's returning a double value which was stored in user defaults.

In code, `SELECTED_SITE_ID` macro is using for more than 1000 places like this,

```
int a = SELECTED_SITE_ID;
NSArray *array = [someClassObject objectAtIndex:a-1];
```

As my app is running for the first time, `SELECTED_SITE_ID` macro is returning 0.0, that's assigned to `int a;` so `a` will be `0`.

Where from array, I have written `a-1` to 0-1, this leads to a crash issue.

I don't know what's the quick way to fix this for now, as it's written at approx. 1000 places?

**What I think?**

> I guess inside macro itself? If I would able to check, what's the value coming? if it's 0 then I will explicitly return 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the problem, you can simply change the macro to do that! Or are you asking *how* to change the macro?

Comment: I'm not sure, how to change the macro? @luk2302

Comment: Try using a ternary operator or the `MAX` macro.

Comment: @luk2302, thanks for your tip, I have resolved it like this, `#define SELECTED_SITE_ID ((SITE_MANAGER.selectedSite.siteCollectionIdentifier <= 0.0) ? 1 : SITE_MANAGER.selectedSite.siteCollectionIdentifier)`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with macros.  The code is simply broken regardless of introducing it long-hand or via macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was easy,

```
#define SELECTED_SITE_ID ((SITE_MANAGER.selectedSite.siteCollectionIdentifier <= 0.0) ? 1 : SITE_MANAGER.selectedSite.siteCollectionIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is:

#define SELECTED_SITE_ID (SITE_MANAGER.selectedSite.siteCollectionIdentifier? :1)

Comment: Not really.  A better way is to have the getter for `siteCollectionIdentifier` return an integer and never return `< 0`.  This is *much* more efficient.  Also that `1` looks wrong, or is it me?

Comment: Agree with @trojanfoe. If possible write getter method for siteCollectionIdentifier.